# Drupal 7 - Place field descriptions above the field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

By default in Drupal 7, field descriptions appear below the field. Is there anyway to move them above the field?

In Drupal 6, you could paste the following code in template.php to move the descriptions. However, the code does not work in Drupal 7:

```
/**
 * Place CCK Options above field .
 */

function ThemeNAME_form_element($element, $value) {
  $output  = ' <div class="form-item"';
  if(!empty($element['#id'])) {
    $output .= ' id="'. $element['#id'] .'-wrapper"';
  }  
  $output .= ">\n";
  $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '<span class="form-required" title="'.t('This field is required.').'">*</span>' : '';

  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    $title = $element['#title'];
    if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
      $output .= ' <label for="'. $element['#id'] .'">'. t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) ."</label> \n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= ' <label>'. t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) ."</label>\n";
    }   
  }

  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' <div class="description">' . $element['#description'] ."</div> \n";
  }

  $output .= " $value\n";
  $output .= " </div> \n";
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and accomplished this by adding it to my theme's template.php file.

```
/**
* Replacement for theme_webform_element() to enable descriptions to come BEFORE the field to be filled out.
*/
function danland_webform_element($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $value = $variables['element']['#children'];

  $wrapper_classes = array(
    'form-item',
  );
  $output = '<div class="' . implode(' ', $wrapper_classes) . '" id="' . $element['#id'] . '-wrapper">' . "\n";
  $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required.') . '">*</span>' : '';

  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    $title = $element['#title'];
    $output .= ' <label for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
  }

  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' <div class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</div>\n";
  }

  $output .= '<div id="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . $value . '</div>' . "\n";

  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;
}
```

Don't forget to clear your cache!

Comment: This works perfectly, except the function name should be _form_element ($variables) (instead of webform_element($variables))

Comment: theme_form_element in D7

Answer (score 2):

https://drupal.org/project/label_help should also do the trick.  Hope that helps

Comment: Keep in mind, Label Help is not as of this writing [currently compatible](https://www.drupal.org/node/1882908) with Webform.

Comment: While this answer is over a year old and the link is helpful it would be better if you post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a theme override for the specific field you want to change or a more general override for all fields. Read this:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/theme_field/7

You shouldn't have to mess with template.php at all to do this.

Comment: I don't think this is valid.  `theme_field` only affects the view of a node, and not the form used to edit or create the node.  I'd have to double check that but I'm pretty certain.

Answer (score 0):

Rumblewand's answer, with a conditional that prevents radio/checkboxes from also being thrown into a div above the input. (May be more efficient ways to do this.)

```
    function theme_form_element($variables) {

      $element = $variables['element'];
      $value = $variables['element']['#children'];

      $wrapper_classes = array(
        'form-item'
      );

      $output = '<div class="' . implode(' ', $wrapper_classes) . '" id="' . $element['#id'] . '-wrapper">' . "\n";

      $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required.') . '">*</span>' : '';

        //Separate treatment for radio buttons & checkboxes
        if (($element['#type'] == 'radio') || ($element['#type'] == 'checkbox')) {
          //vs outputting input in its own div separate from label
          $output .=  $value . "\n";  

          if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
            $output .= '<span class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</span>\n";
          }

          if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
            $title = $element['#title'];
            $output .= '<label class="option" for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . t('!title !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
          }

      } else {

          if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
            $title = $element['#title'];
            $output .= ' <label for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . t('!title !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
          }

          if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
            $output .= '<div class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</div>\n";
          }

          $output .= '<div id="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . $value . '</div>' . "\n";  

      }

      $output .= "</div>\n";

      return $output;

    }
```